# Django: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Tags: python, django, google-chrome, django-rest-framework

I'm writing an API for django & django-rest. I used to develop it on ubuntu, but when I switched to windows I've started getting these errors on every response from django.

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 54161)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\envs\project\lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\envs\project\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\envs\project\lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\envs\project\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 174, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\envs\project\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 182, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\envs\project\lib\socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

Developer tools also show me that this connection was cancelled. I have firewall & anti-virus programs disabled.
[image]

This is the only lin in my `/etc/hosts/`

```
127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain localhost
```

I'm using windows 10.

```
Python              3.86
Django              3.1.2
django-cors-headers 3.5.0
djangorestframework 3.12.1
```

Do you know how to help this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with the timeout on a client-side. By default some browsers set very small timeout number (1s in my case). And when server couldn't process the request aborted the connection.

I've fixed it by setting the timeout to `5s`.

Comment: How did you adjust the timeout?

Comment: I use `axios` as a library for making REST calls. There I just adjusted the main config with

`
timeout: 5
`